A movie about a teen who witnesses strange behavior from his neighbor
This is a Hollywood movie, in English, released sometime after 2003.  Probably late 00's.  The star was a teen, but I feel like he is someone now considered famous, like Jake Gyllenhall or Tobey Maguire or someone.  Anyway, he's grounded for some reason or other.  He sees a guy that lives across the street possibly commit a crime or something.  Maybe murders his family?  I remember the teen's girlfriend climbs into his upstairs bedroom via a lower roof at some point, or maybe he climbs out onto said roof to hang out with her.  I also kind of remember him sending a remote control car with a camera on it into his neighbor's garage to look around the house to see if he can figure out what happened.
Does this sound familiar to anyone?

And it's not Disturbia? (I don't remember an RC car there)

There was a camera, but I don't remember one on an rc car.

This sounds like "Disturbia (2007)".

After his father is killed in a car accident, things unravel for Kale Brecht and he is placed under house-arrest for punching his Spanish teacher. Having nothing better to do, Kale occupies himself by spying on his neighbors. But one night, he witnesses what appears to be a murder going on in Mr. Turner's house. Kale becomes obsessed with uncovering the truth behind these murders but, after a few unsettling run-ins with Mr. Turner, it becomes a matter of life and death. And the ominous question: Who is watching whom?

The trailer
This fits your details of the character being played by a young famous teenage actor (Shia LaBeouf), he does have a girlfriend, Ashley (played by Sarah Roemer). Though honestly I haven't seen the movie to verify any of the other details.

Well, if it is, this is probably the 3rd or 4th time this came up on ID.

This sounds like it.  I'll check it out and give you the mark if it's the one, but I think it is.

@Walt - actually, only 2 of 4 Disturbia-related questions here are IDs. The others question plot elements.

I was about to say Disturbia. I think onewho hit the nail on the head.
